# Rendering the Tweet button on a non-anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I have an anchor that encompasses various elements, as it makes it touch friendly and is valid html5:

```
<a href="whatever.html">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Paragraph</p>
</a>
```

Now, I want to add a Tweet button to this anchor. However, nesting anchors is invalid in html5. So this will render the Twitter iframe outside the anchor:

```
<a href="whatever.html">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Paragraph</p>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">...</a>
</a>
```

And if I change the markup to say something like this it won't render the button:

```
<a href="whatever.html">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Paragraph</p>
   <div class="twitter-share-button">...</div>
</a>
```

The facebook like button renders fine as it doesn't require an anchor element to work. Anybody know a workaround for Twitter? Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xdEwg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I hacked this horribly by putting it outside of the anchor and using position absolute, such as...

```
<div class="module">
  <a href="whatever.html">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">...</a>
</div>

.module {
  position: relative; 
}
.twitter-share-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

But I'm still interested in a workaround.

Comment: I tried for a bit, sounds like this probably the best way to do it. You can't invoke a click on an anchor tag that's inside an iFrame, nor could try to change how Twitter is forming button as it's linking to a script that inserts the iFrame. So unless you wanna get **really** hacky I'd go with what you got